# How would I make something spawn when and where a snowball hits something?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to make things spawn as they follow an object, but is there any way to make them spawn once lets say a snowball hits its target?

I am working on a way to make snowballs that spawn tnt upon hitting their target.

Comment: While this question is bumped, can minecraft command-savvy people go and downvote the answers that are straight-up *wrong*?

Answer (score 9):

I have found a solution that works relatively well. The main issue is that when a snowball lands, the entity disappears immediately. To counteract this, we can use an armor stand marker to track the last known location of the snowball. This is not *exactly* where the snowball hits, but close enough for practical purposes.

First, you need to set up a scoreboard objective to track the snowball's lifetime, and another to detect a lonely armorstand.

```
/scoreboard objectives add snowballTime dummy
/scoreboard objectives add hasSnowball dummy
```

Now, create a fill clock (or use 1.9's repeat/chain command blocks), and run the following commands:

```
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Snowball] snowballTime 1

/execute @e[type=Snowball,score_snowballTime=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {NoGravity:1b,CustomName:"SnowballMarker",Marker:1b,Invisible:1b}
/execute @e[type=Snowball,score_snowballTime_min=2] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SnowballMarker,c=1] @e[type=Snowball,r=1]

/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SnowballMarker] hasSnowball 0
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SnowballMarker,r=1] hasSnowball 1

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SnowballMarker,score_hasSnowball=0] ~ ~ ~ summon PrimedTnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0}
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SnowballMarker,score_hasSnowball=0]
```

The first command will assign an ever-increasing score to every snowball entity in the world. The second and third commands will either create a new (invisible, hitboxless) armor stand (called "SnowballMarker") at the location of the snowball, or teleport an existing one to the snowball.

The fourth and fifth commands will set the `hasSnowball` score on the armor stand to 0 or 1, depending on whether or not there is a snowball within a radius of 1 block.

Command 6 summons TNT at every armor stand that does not have a snowball, and the last command removes these armor stands afterwards. Set the `Fuse` to whatever you like.

(I you are curious about the way this works, I suggest removing `Invisible:1b` from the summon command of the armor stand, so you can see them in action)

Comment: `hasSnowball` can be a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach: When the snowball is thrown, summon an ArmorStand at its location. (using `execute` on the snowball). And use it to track the snowball. When the snowball hits something, it disappears and the ArmorStands SBB score starts to increase. You can use this to summon a TNT at the Spot where the snowball "died":

`execute @e[type=Snowball,score_SBB_min=1,score_SBB=1] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"SBTracker",Marker:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b}`
(SBB=Snowballbomb, you have to create this objective first)

Teleport every ArmorStand to "its" Snowball:
`execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=SBTracker] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[c=1] @e[type=Snowball,r=2]`

At every gametick, increase every snowballs SBB score by one:
`scoreboard players add @e[type=Snowball] SBB 1`

Do the same to the ArmorStands:
`scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand] SBB 1`

Reset every ArmorStands SBB to 0 when there is a snowball nearby:
`execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,r=2] SBB 0`

Summon a TNT at every ArmorStand with a SBB score of more than one:
`execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_SBB_min=2,score_SBB=2] ~ ~ ~ /summon PrimedTNT ~ ~ ~`

Kill every ArmorStand with a SBB score of at least 3:
`kill @e[type=ArmorStand,score_SBB_min=3]`

Comment: You talk about "(taking) a different approach", but this answer is functionally identical to [mine](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/234018/74333), with the only difference being that you use the same scoreboard objective for the armor stands and the snowballs.

Comment: Strange, I somehow didnt see your answer... But why do you use 2 objectives?

Comment: Keeping things a bit more sorted and clear, I guess. I just didn't think about using the same objective for both.

Answer (score -1):

### Fixed! Fully functional 1.8/1.8.x

Enter in a command block

```
/testfor @e[type=Snowball]
```

Then, power this with a clock.
To make a clock, type

```
/gamerule dotiledrops false
```

and then set a Redstone Block on top of a command block that has this command:

```
/setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 minecraft:redstone_block 0 destroy
```

Then set two comparators on two sides of the original /testfor command block. Then, place a command block on the ends of both of the comparators pointing away from the /testfor command block. In one, place the command

```
/summon PrimedTnt ~20 ~-20 ~ {Fuse:whateveryouwant30reccomended} ~ ~ ~
```

In the other, place the command

```
/tp @e[type=PrimedTnt,c=-1] @e[type=Snowball,c=-1]
```

Comment: This is outright horrible. 1) There is no need to turn off tile drops to make a clock. 2) The summon command has syntax errors, and could be summoning to the snowballs directly using execute. 3) the tp command teleports *every* Tnt to *every* snowball (Which I don't even know how the game will handle it).

Comment: the answer has not answered his question, and he raises very valid points. Why do you say "we are making a clock" and then call the line to disable tiles dropping? I do not play minecraft **and even I can tell this is very incorrect**. There is no reason to vandalise the question, just because your answer was not accepted. We expect a certain level of quality, here, and accuracy is one of the biggest factors that trumps all.

Answer (score -1):

```
/scoreboard objectives add lifetime dummy 
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Snowball] lifetime 0
```

the screboard is so the tnt doesnt explode in ur face
then do

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ /testfor @a[r=2]
```

so it tests for a player in a range of 2 blocks

```
/execute @e[type=Snowball,score_lifetime_min=4] ~ ~ ~ /summon PrimedTnt
```

also do `/gamerule commandblockoutput false or it'll spam the chat`

Comment: Apart from the missing formatting and largely missing explanation, this doesn't even make sense (potentially because of the latter): 1) Your lifetime score will always be at 0, since you are adding 0. 2) Your execute/testfor *doesn't do anything*. Is is supposed to be hooked up to a comparator running into the third command?

Answer (score -1):

I may have an idea (Either bad or good) Score Command:`

> /scoreboard objectives add snowballtime dummy

So this is how I think that this can work. 
Hook this command to a clock:

> /execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ detect ~1 ~ ~ [block] scoreboard players add @e[type=Snowball] snowballtime 1

You will need to copy this command a lot of times and change the 
"detect ~ ~1 ~", "detect ~ ~-1 ~",etc. so it will detect a block in any direction in a 1 block radius.

Then add a redstone comparator pointing to this command:

> /execute @e[type=Snowball,score_snowballtime=1] ~ ~ ~ summon PrimedTnt ~ ~ ~ {Fuse:0}

and a command behind that:

> /execute @e[type=Snowball] ~ ~ ~ detect [~? ~? ~?] [block] scoreboard players set @e[type=Snowball] snowballtime 0

I hope that can help, plus I am just getting some ideas for commands for maps and minigames.

Comment: I see multiple issues here. The detect syntax of the execute command requires you to specify a specific block. Meaning you'd need about 6 times the number of blocks in the game command blocks for this. Also, the snowball would blow up in your face if you throw it while adjacent to a wall (or ceiling)