# How do I create a "ThrownEgg" entity with a 100% chance to spawn a chick when broken?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm asking this for a minigame I'm making. The egg should spawn a chick when broken, every time, as opposed to the 1/8 chance the egg normally has of producing a chick.

I don't want to have to create any mods or plugins for this either. Perhaps my first question should be, "Is it even possible?"

Comment: There is sadly no way to do this directly via NBT data, but you could try using a modified version of [my answer to a related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/234018/74333). The positioning is not quite exact, and you'll probably end up with 9/8 chicken/egg thrown, however.

Comment: You could just make a resource pack and replace the snowball texture with the egg texture and just give the player snowballs instead of eggs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an armor stand to follow the egg and summon chicks when the armor stand loses the snowball.

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Stand dummy
/scoreboard objectives add hasStand dummy
/scoreboard objectives add hasEgg dummy
```

Clock:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] Stand 1 {Marker:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1}
/execute @e[type=ThrownEgg,score_hasStand_min=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Stand_min=1,c=1] @e[type=ThrownEgg,score_hasStand_min=1,c=1,r=1]
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ThrownEgg] hasStand 0
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Stand_min=1] hasEgg 0
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Stand_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=ThrownEgg,r=1,c=1] hasStand 1
/execute @e[type=ThrownEgg,r=1,c=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Stand_min=1] hasEgg 1
/execute @e[type=ThrownEgg,score_hasStand=0] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,Invisible:1,NoGravity:1}
/scoreboard players @e[type=ThrownEgg] hasStand 1
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Stand_min=1,score_hasEgg=0] ~ ~ ~ summon Chicken ~ ~ ~ {Age:-400}
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,score_Stand_min=1,score_hasEgg=0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! For whatever reason, I though I would have to edit the egg's NBT, but this method is much simpler.